# How to bind the current element to a click handler using on

Tags: jquery

In jQuery 1.9+ you don't use the live handler anymore because "on" exists. If I'm using on and I want to bind the "button" clicked how would I do so?

Currenly this only binds the event (not the element that I need in the function)

```
var like = function(el) {
    //var el = $("#like"); (to avoid this)
    $(el).parent().hide();
};

$("#like").on('click', like);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`el` is a [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object.

`el.target` is the [DOM element](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) that triggered the click.

`this` is a pre-configured reference to that DOM element.

`$(this)` converts that reference into a jQuery reference.

So you can go like this

```
var like = function(el) {
     console.log(el); // outputs event object object
     console.log(el.target); // outputs DOM element
     console.log(this); // should output the same as el.target
     console.log($(this)); // outputs jQuery object of that DOM element

     // the code can be
     $(this).parent().hide();
     // or
     $(el.target).parent().hide();
}
```

Comment: `el is a jQuery.Event object` . It is an **event object** and not a **Jquery.Event Object**

Comment: @Sushanth-- I'm sure it's a jQuery.Event object. As long as the callback was used with a jQuery event handler. jQuery will create a jQuery.Event object and pass that as the first argument, and then it will set the DOM element as the context for the call to the event.

Comment: @Sushanth-- You're right. No such thing as a jQuery.Event object. There is a factory method called jQuery.Event, but I can't find anything defined as jQuery.Event

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` context inside the handler, which is the element that generated the event.

```
var like = function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
};

$("#like").on('click', like);
```